# VB.Net Image Resource returning Nothing when calling My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I already kind of found a solution for this earlier but wanted to ask why this was an issue in the first place.

I embedded some images of country flags, named by their ISO Alpha-2 codes...ex. us.png

Some of the images were not being returned when calling My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("in") (which would return the country flag of india, as in.png is included as a resource, and no errors in console...)

I solved this by simply adding "flag_" to the beginning of all filenames, as I suspect "in" was causing some problems for being a reserved keyword?  Some other countries also had the same issues, but no visible error would be thrown...

Just wondering if someone could explain why this wasn't throwing an error?

Comment: How did you get a resource named 'in'?  I tried to reproduce but when I added an existing file with the name 'in' the system added an '_' to the beginning of the name and when creating a new resource it complained about the name 'in'.

Comment: @dbasnett Hi, sorry for the slow response.  I added the resource by right clicking my project, going to properties, then resources, changing from strings to images, then adding a directory containing the flag pngs.  When they were added, it was showing as in.png in my resources folder, but again was returning Nothing when calling ResourceManager.GetObject()

Using VS2015, haven't updated it in awhile though.  Anyways this was just a minor annoyance, it was easy enough to just rename the filenames that were giving me problems before importing them as embedded resources.

Comment: I don't know how to add a directory.  I can add the contents of a directory several different ways, but with the same result, in became _in.